# Virtual Memory not working on Windows11 VHDX with Intune

Tags: virtual-memory, vhd, intune

I'm using bootable VHDx with Windows11. My company ask me to register my laptop with Enterprise Portal (Intune); i have to encrypt my drive using Bitlocker for that. When i start from a brand new VHDX, everything is ok regarding the virtual memory (pagefile.sys is in place, working properly and the UI reflect this). But as soon as i encrypt my drive and join Enterprise Portal, on the next reboot, the Performance Options screen popup after login and the Virtual Memory is "unset"; there is no way to make that work, i tried every option (Automatically manage, custom size on C:, custome size on D:) whenever i reboot, the Performance Options screen popup after login and there is no more Virtual Memory settings.

I tried to "unjoin" my company portal and unencrypt my drive; but even after that, there is no way to make the Virtual Memory works.

This problem does not happens on physical device joining the company portal.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you contacted your System Administrator for assistance with this problem, as it likely will require, an Administrator to solve

Comment: Yep, they have no clue what is this problem.  It seems that i'm the only one trying to work with VHD